# How to set value vc-git-grep-template within function

Tags: customize, functions, setq

I have a working sexp for configuration `vc-git-grep`:

```
(setq vc-git-grep-template "git --no-pager grep -n -i -e <R> -- <F>")
```

Then in `dired-mode` I evaluate `M-x` `vc-git-grep` and everething works as expected.

And then I want to create defun:

```
(defun Pfedj/vc-git-grep-noncase()
  (interactive)
  (setq vc-git-grep-template "git --no-pager grep -n -i -e <R> -- <F>")
  (vc-git-grep))
```

When in `dired-mode` I evaluate

`M-x` `Pfedj/vc-git-grep-template`

==> Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 3), 0

How can I fix my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vc-git-grep` is an interactive function which prompts, so when you want to call it from your own code you need to use `call-interactively`, otherwise it expects you to have supplied its required arguments in the call:

```
(defun Pfedj/vc-git-grep-noncase()
  (interactive)
  (setq vc-git-grep-template "git --no-pager grep -n -i -e <R> -- <F>")
  (call-interactively #'vc-git-grep))
```